# How to always write numbers with decimal points instead of commas with Android

Tags: java, android

I write files and read them back.  I use a comma delimited file format so that Excel can read the files easily.  This works fine for me but my Dutch friend can't get the program to work.  The problem is that when I write out 52.345 what ends up in the file is 52,345 and when I read it back I get 52 and then 345 as the next field.

This is not a matter of formatting numbers as this behavior happens from many sources, from edit text that the user enters, from character sequences converted to strings, as well as from numbers being written with format commands.  There are hundreds of instances in the code so I need something universal that covers all default behavior and forces it to Locale.US

What I need is a way to program the app so it makes the tablet to just act like a Locale.US tablet in every way, keyboard, number writing, etc.  I am not looking for a way to change one line of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`String.format (String format, Object... args)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) with not mandatory Locale argument, specified explicitely to [`Locale.US`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#US) :

*Assuming plong is double or float and not long, cause no need decimal point for long.*

```
waypointArray[0][2] = String.format(Locale.US, "%f", pLong);
```

Or, if you need this for all the application, this in onCreate of the activity, or in a class extending application :

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = Locale.US;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
  getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Comment: I think the code that is messing us is this    waypointArray[0][2] = pLong.toString(); and when I write the string out, it is already wrong.

Comment: Use this instead : `waypointArray[0][2] = String.format(Locale.US, "%f", pLong);`

Comment: Is there a way to just make the entire app or at least class use Locale.US?  I have hundreds of places to put "Locale.US" otherwise.  There are 35 classes in this app but tons of places where I should have specified the Locale.

Comment: I have sent a file off to be tested as I can't test it here in the US.  Thank you for your help.  I will be sure to mark it as solved when I hear back.

Comment: You can set language of your Android phone to French to test.

Comment: My Dutch friend reports success.  Thank you. @gahfy, can you tell me if I need to put this code in every class or just run it once per application?